# Need Regex that selects lines of text

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will take certain lines of text separated by either commas or returns. What I want to do is, say, I have a body of text, short words (customer names) and I have 32 names all in a column each with a return. I want to split the column into separate columns of, say, 5 deep. The last column in this example would be only 2 deep. I can make my 32 name list in columns or separated by commas. A separate regex for each column or part column is fine actually preferable. My list will always vary from 1 name up to 60 names. So if I had a regex that could choose line 6 to line 10, and another that picks line 11 to line 15 that would be awesome. If anyone can provide a regex that will do that I will love that person for the rest of my life. :)

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to show input data and expected output.  What language are you using?  We are here to help you, not do your job.

Comment: I'm using a prepress workflow called Esko Automation Engine. With it i can create "smart names". Some smart names have the option to enter Regular Expressions. Never heard of them before so I googled it and was able to come up with ^[^\n]+?([^\n]{7})$ which selects the last 7 characters. Used to shorten 128 Bar Codes. But how to write one that selects various lines of copy is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Using commas will lead you down the path of parsing CSVs with regex, which is bad, but if you know your data won't contain commas, should work fine. Otherwise, there is little documentation on multiple line matching with SmartNames, so I am not sure how well this will work. Unfortunately, the regex engine only extracts the first group and has no provision for non-extracting groups, so you can't use numeric quantifiers, but must repeat the matches. Hopefully there isn't a length limitation.

So to extract the 6 through 10 lines, skip over the first five then extract 5:

```
^.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n(.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n)
```

If you are using commas, just replace `\n` with `,`.

In general, to extract the nth - nth+y lines, start with `^`, add `.+\n` (n-1) times, then put in `(`, `.+\n` (y+1) times, then `)`. So to extract lines 11 to 15,

```
^.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n(.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n)
```